# How to list down the list of PDB and CDB in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

What is the SQL command to return a list of PDB and CDB in Oracle?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_mon.htm#ADMIN13719

Answer (score 9):

DBA_PDBS views will list you the pluggable databases and their current state. PDB$SEED will be listed, but it's not one of your pluggable databases, not one that you would worry about anyway.

```
select * from DBA_PDBS order by pdb_id
```

[image]

Comment: what is the sql command?

Comment: select * from, basically @Beki